# Exception while calling stored procedure from jdbc

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

Calling a stored procedure results in this exception:

> SQLException1 java.sql.SQLException: User does not have access to
>   metadata  required to determine stored procedure parameter types.  If
>   rights can not be granted, configure connection with
>   "noAccessToProcedureBodies=true" to have driver generate parameters
>   that represent INOUT strings irregardless of actual parameter types.

To resolve this, I tried:

```
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306
/database?useInformationSchema=true&noAccessToProcedureBodies=true", 
"user_name", "pasword");
```

But it still does not work.

I am using shared hosting.

I am using

- Software version: 5.0.91-community-log - MySQL Community Edition (GPL)
- Protocol version: 10
- Java 1.6
- mysql-connector-java-5.1.14-bin.jar

One of my stored procedures is:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `share_message` 

DELIMITER //


CREATE PROCEDURE share_message(in messageid1 int(200),in received_by1 int(20),
in sent_by1 int(20),in shared_of1 int(20),author1 int(20), OUT query_status1 TINYINT)

BEGIN


DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
  BEGIN
    -- ERROR
   SET query_status1 = -1;
    rollback;
  END;

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING
  BEGIN
    -- WARNING
   SET query_status1 = -1;
    rollback;
  END;

START TRANSACTION;
SET query_status1 = 0;



INSERT INTO post_message_users(messageid,received_by,sent_by,shared_of,author) 
VALUES(messageid1,received_by1,sent_by1,shared_of1,author1);

UPDATE  post_messages SET total_share=total_share+1 WHERE messageid=messageid1;


SET query_status1 =1;


COMMIT;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

This is working properly with my local database.

Comment: Post the text of your stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the stored procedure you are attempting to use needs access to MySQL's `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`. That's a (fake) database built in every MySQL server; it's used to fetch descriptions of tables, columns, indexes, and the like.

It looks like the user id you're using doesn't have access to the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`. That's understandable on a hosting service.

Go on MyPhpAdmin and try a query like this to be sure about that.

```
 SELECT table_schema, table_name
   FROM information_schema.columns       
  WHERE column_name = 'something'
    AND table_schema = 'your database name'
```

If you get some kind of error saying you don't have permission, this is definitely your problem.

You could try rewriting your stored proc, or you could ask your hosting service to grant you the appropriate priv.

Comment: I have tried above query which is executing properly and giving table_schema and table_name

Comment: Initially I tried `"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306
/database?noAccessToProcedureBodies=true", 
"user_name", "pasword")`then I included `useInformationSchema=true`

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; Change your Java code, make the CallableStatement reference parameters by index instead of name.

After having a similar problem I updated my JDBC driver mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar.
The error then changed from

> User does not have access to metadata required to determine stored
>   procedure parameter types. If rights can not be granted, configure
>   connection with "noAccessToProcedureBodies=true" to have driver
>   generate parameters that represent INOUT strings irregardless of
>   actual parameter types.

to

> No access to parameters by name when connection has been configured not to access procedure bodies

I changed my Callable Statement to reference parameters by index instead of name, and hey presto it works.

Updating the driver may not be necessary, just knowing to use indexes instead of names when you don't have metadata access or routine body access.

Good Luck